# How to remove outliers along with factor variables?

Tags: r

I am trying to remove outliers from a dataset `s` consisted of 3 variables:

```
id consumption period
 a      0.1    summer
 a      0.2    summer
 b      0.3    summer
 a      0.4    winter
 b      10     winter
 c      12     winter
```

I used `outliers <- s$consumption[!s$consumption %in% boxplot.stats(s$consumption)$out]` to remove the outliers from `s` and got something like this:

```
consumption
   0.1
   0.2
   0.3
   0.4
```

However, I want to get something like this below:

```
id consumption period
 a      0.1    summer
 a      0.2    summer
 b      0.3    summer
 a      0.4    winter
```

But the `$out` function only allows me to remove the column with numbers (not with factors).

Comment: `out <- s[!s$consumption %in% boxplot.stats(s$consumption)$out, ]`

Comment: I tried your code but it says undefined columns selected.

Comment: Are you sure you have copied the code correctly? Specially placing of commas ? I am not selecting any columns but only rows in this code.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't copy correctly. I also figured out a less simplified solution, you may have a check if interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which is to find the `min` of the output I got from `outliers <- s$consumption[!s$consumption %in% boxplot.stats(s$consumption)$out]`, which is `l` in this case:

```
consumption
   0.1
   0.2
   0.3
   0.4
```

By knowing my `min` value, I can then take a subset of `s` by setting a condition where `consumption` has to be less than `min(l)`.

`new <- subset(s, consumption < min(l))`